# Base16 with custom hextable

Tags: c, ios, hex

I'd like to encode/decode data using Base16 but with a custom hextable (as opposed to the conventional '0123456789ABCDEF')

I've considered simply replacing every digit/letter with the corresponding one after writing it but I find that inefficient for obvious reasons

This is for an iphone app, which means I'm using objective-c code but that C and C++ also work with it.

I tried the code here: http://www.koders.com/c/fid4FE13B3E182CA09D7F399059A96DBF0A7968BA5C.aspx?s=base64

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#  include <config.h>
#endif

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "ggz.h"
#include "base16.h"

/* Function to encode strings to base16 (hex) with a nibble per hex character */

char *ggz_base16_encode(const char *text, int length)
{
    char *ret = NULL;
    int i;
    static const char hextable[20] = "0123456789abcdef";

    if(!text) return NULL;

    ret = ggz_malloc((length * 2 + 1)*sizeof(*ret));
    if(!ret) return NULL;

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        ret[i*2] = hextable[(text[i]&0xf0)>>4];
        ret[i*2+1] = hextable[text[i]&0xf];
    }
    return ret;
}
```

But I don't find the decoding method on the same site, and also its not working anyways. This is my corresponding objective-c code for it:

```
NSString *txt = @"hello";
NSData *data = [txt dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
const char *nc = ggz_base16_encode(data.bytes, [data length]);
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:nc encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Decoding code should be simple, like that:

```
int result = 0;
for each char c in string (left to right)
    result = result * 16 + getNumericValue(c)
```

(pseudocode!)

For `getNumericValue` I would use, generally speaking, a pre-filled map (dictionary/hashtable/whatever your favourite language has), which just maps char to its numeric value.

For conventional hex notation, one could construct the map as follows:

```
for (int i = '0'; i <= '9'; i++)
    map[i] = i - '0';
for (int i = 'a'; i <= 'f'; i++)
    map[i] = i - 'a' + 10;
```

-- but for your special mapping you would need your customary table.

(I'm not an expert in objective C, so I don't know what are the appropriate data structures there.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this compiles, it is simulated in C. ggz_malloc does garbage collect?

```
char * ggz_base16_decode(const char *text)
{
    const char * customtable = "0123456789abcdef";
    int size = strlen(text);
    char * ret = ggz_malloc((size+1)>>1);
    char * q = ret;
    int i;
    int f = 1;
    unsigned char t[256];
    memset(t,0,256);
    i = 0; while (*customtable) t[*customtable++]=i++;
    while (*text) {
            if (f) *q = t[*text]<<4;
            else *q++ |= t[*text];
            f = !f;
            ++text;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the expression

```
ret[i*2] = hextable[(text[i]&0xf0)>>4];
```

might be going wrong. I think char is signed.

If the value of `text[i]` has its top bit set say `0xe0`, then the `0xe0 & 0xf0` = `0xe0`, then `0xe0 >> 4` is `0xfe` because it is sign extended. so it will be looking up way beyond the end of hextable.

So try

```
ret[i*2] = hextable[(text[i]>>4)&0x0f];
```